# Mac OS X Lion: every time I shutdown or restart my lap…chrome and textmate open?

Tags: macos, startup, startup-error

Every time I turn on or restart Mac OS X Lion...chrome and textmate open. Even if I uncheck "Reopen windows when logging back in" before shutdown or restart. Chrome and textmate do not appear on loggin items on Users & Groups from System Preferences so I can't uncheck them. Is very weird and I don't really know what to do. Some good ideas? Thanks!

I also delete textmate and chrome files from ~/Library/Saved Application State. But it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run these two commands in a terminal:

```
curl http://goo.gl/Z4EFC -L -s -o ~/fixlogin.sh
chmod +x ~/fixlogin.sh && sudo ~/fixlogin.sh ; rm ~/fixlogin.sh
```

The contents of the downloaded script are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "#!/bin/bash" > /tmp/loginfix.sh
echo "rm /Users/*/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.loginwindow.*" >> /tmp/loginfix.sh
mv /tmp/loginfix.sh /usr/bin/loginfix.sh
chmod +x /usr/bin/loginfix.sh
defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /usr/bin/loginfix.sh
```

The state of the checkbox won't matter anymore, windows won't be getting restored

Or you could just [upgrade lion to 10.7.4](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5167), they fixed that bug

Comment: thank you very much, upgrading worked! I upgraded and then delete chrome and textmate files from ~/library/Saved Application State.

Answer (score 0):

Update your OS. There is a [Lion patch](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5167) that came out recently that addresses broken functionality related to re-opening applications at login.